# $http Cross Origin Request Blocked by Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors

I am trying to implement search suggestion using one of our Suggestions API "https://SuggestionsAPI.net/suggest?key=xyz" which is working fine with Ajax GET request but when I am trying to use it with Angular $http service, it is throwing me error is console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote 
resource at https://SuggestionsAPI.net/suggest?key=xyz. This can be fixed by moving the 
resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

Further I tried :

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' };
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, accept, content-type' };
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST' };
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = { 'dataType': 'jsonp' };
```

I am stuck here thinking why same GET request is blocked by browser when using Angular JS. Please suggest me to eliminate it.

EDIT: My next step id to assign the suggestions inside a function:

```
app.directive('autoComplete', ['AutoCompleteService', function (AutoCompleteService) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
        elem.autocomplete({
            source: function (searchTerm, response) {
                AutoCompleteService.search(searchTerm.term).then(function (autocompleteResults) {
                    response($.map(autocompleteResults, function (autocompleteResult) {
                        return {
                            label: autocompleteResult.JumboID,
                            value: autocompleteResult.JumboID
                        }
                    }))
                });
            },
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, selectedItem) {
                // Do something with the selected item, e.g. 
                scope.yourObject = selectedItem.item.value;
                scope.$apply();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

}]);

Comment: Since the request is cross domain. Either your server should be configured with CORS, or should be able to handle JSONP request from client. You have not detailed about the server impelmentation.

Comment: @Chandermani the CORS issue is resolved by A.B's answer but another error is coming saying " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" becuase I can see my URL is translated to suggest?query=8645&callback=angular.callbacks._1:1 ? Any thoughts how to remove ":"from request?

Answer (score 2):

append `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to your url like `https://SuggestionsAPI.net/suggest?key=xyz&callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

then use `jsonp`

```
$http.jsonp(url).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //here
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //
    });
```

Comment: CORS headers aren't needed for jsonp, it's a script request. Also not all API's support jsonp

Comment: Got "suggest?query=6654&subscription-key=ca67c22cba91492c85c58a8e7a825031&callback=angular.callbacks._0:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token " @A.B

Comment: Unexpected token ":", why request got appended by _N:1, please suggest as I am getting correct response from URL, still console is throwing the error! Any Ideas @A.B

Comment: what are you loggin to console and which line is giving error

Comment: {"@odata.context":"https://SuggestionsAPI.net/indexes('jumboindex')/$metadata#docs(JumboID)","value":[{"@search.text":"864485345","JumboID":"e3ef41a7f79e1f97b9a2e0fceb6ee2ce:80880b9b1d7261f24c4e1c341853ec4e"},{"@search.text":"86406653","JumboID":"cd13f897f315b8e3c8a792976b1f070e:80880b9b1d7261f24c4e1c341853ec4e"},{"@search.text":"86408729","JumboID":"716088e5555d737041b24e750d591c4c:80880b9b1d7261f24c4e1c341853ec4e"},{"@search.text":"8640 South River Parkway Tempe Arizona 85284","JumboID":"5d18fd8d570adc49b48012f2ba434bf3:80880b9b1d7261f24c4e1c341853ec4e"}]}

Comment: this is my response form server as I searched 8640, I think which is not a valid JSONP

Comment: you are getting it in success of jsonp?

Comment: i think you have got the corect data just assign to varaible and iterate over it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67888/discussion-between-tom-and-a-b).

Comment: I have edited the code showing how I am handling the response in Directive creation, please have a look